# Yii2 ExportMenu - Kartik-v Экспорт в pdf

Tags: php, html5, yii2, yii, mpdf

сделал по документации экспорт в PDF таблицы(gridview), но как сделать чтобы в PDF перенести допустим строчку с тегом `<p>` или Любую форму ? В примере ниже есть строка `<p>` подскажите как ее добавить к выводу ? 
Это index.php

```
 <?php

 use yii\helpers\Html;
 use yii\grid\GridView;

 /* @var $this yii\web\View */
 /* @var $searchModel app\models\StatementSearch */
 /* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Statements';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
 ?>
 <div class="statement-index">

<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
<?php
use kartik\export\ExportMenu;
$gridColumns= [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    'idStatement',
    'IdUsers',
    'iddirection',
    'idKids',
    'date',
    'statement_status_idstatement_status',
    'idkids_status',
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
];
echo ExportMenu::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    // 'layout'=>$layout,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,

]);
?>
<?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

<p>What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 
1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also 
the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It 
was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing 
Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software 
like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the 
readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using 
Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as 
opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable 
English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem 
Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will 
uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved 
over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour 
and the like).

</p>
<p>
    <?= Html::a('Create Statement', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn- 
success']) ?>
</p>


<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'idStatement',
       // 'IdUsers',
       [
        'attribute' => 'IdUsers',
        'value' => 'users.username',
        'filter' => $arrUsers,
        ],

        //'iddirection',
            [
        'attribute' => 'iddirection',
        'value' => 'direction.direction_name',
        'filter' => $arrDirection,
        ],
      //  'idKids',

        [ 
        'attribute' => 'idKids',
        'value' => 'kids.KidsName',
        'filter' => $arrKids,
        ],

        'date',


       // 'statement_status_idstatement_status',
        [ 
        'attribute' => 'statement_status_idstatement_status',
        'value' => 'statementStatusIdstatementStatus.name',
        'filter' => $Status,
        ], 



       // 'idkids_status',

    [ 
        'attribute' => 'idkids_status',
        'value' => 'kidsStatus.name',
        'filter' => $arrKidsStatus,
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
<p>
    <?= Html::a('Create Statement', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn- 
success']) ?>
</p>

</div>
```

Вот что он выдает [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Как добавить в PDF текст Lorem?
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Но ведь экспорт идет из базы данных.Создайте в вашей таблице еще один столбец, и добавляйте туда ваш текст.Так он никак не добавит в pdf файл текст